# Align the writing in Two neighboring columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How can I add **line2.** **line3**. in the second row first column so that they are aligned with their counterparts in the second column?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[left=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{bm,amsmath}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.7,0.2,0.8}
\definecolor{bluevert}{rgb}{0,0.9,1}
\definecolor{trustcolor}{rgb}{0.71,0.14,0.07}
\definecolor{PinkTriton}{rgb}{.708 ,.055 ,.275}
\definecolor{RedTriton}{rgb}{.491 ,.097 ,.066} % couleur rouge du triton
\definecolor{OrangeTriton}{rgb}{.953 ,.502 ,.04}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------




\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Input} & Given $ A|_{\theta = 0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -1.0000 & 0.4794\\ 1.0000 & 0.2500\\ 0.2298 & 0.0417\\ 0.5000 & -0.5000\\ 0.7702 & 0.3750\\ 0.1250 & 0.5000 \end{bmatrix}$,
  $ A_{\theta}^{'}|_{\theta = 0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -2.000 & 0.8776\\ 2.0000 & 1.0000\\ 0.8415 & 0.2500\\ 1.0000 & 2.0000\\ -0.8415 & 1.7500\\ 0.7500 & 1.0000 \end{bmatrix}$\\
  \hline
 \textbf{line1.} & Compute $ M = Q^TA_{\theta}^{'}R^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.4216  & 1.7145\\ -0.4229 & 0.9862 \end{bmatrix}$.\\
 & Factorize $M L+D+U = \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 0\\ -0.4229 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 1.4216  & 0\\ 0 & 0.9862 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0  & 1.7145\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.\\
 & Compute $R_{\theta}^{'} = (L^T+D+U)R= \begin{bmatrix}  2.4257   & 1.1468\\ 0 & 0.9510 \end{bmatrix}$ \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{IRMf-TEP Comparaison}
\label{tab:dif_irm_tep}
\end{table}\newpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add then before the relevant `&`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\hline
  \textbf{Input} & Given $ A|_{\theta = 0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -1.0000 & 0.4794\\ 1.0000 & 0.2500\\ 0.2298 & 0.0417\\ 0.5000 & -0.5000\\ 0.7702 & 0.3750\\ 0.1250 & 0.5000 \end{bmatrix}$,
  $ A_{\theta}'|_{\theta = 0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -2.000 & 0.8776\\ 2.0000 & 1.0000\\ 0.8415 & 0.2500\\ 1.0000 & 2.0000\\ -0.8415 & 1.7500\\ 0.7500 & 1.0000 \end{bmatrix}$\\
\hline
  \textbf{line1.} & Compute $ M = Q^TA_{\theta}'R^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.4216  & 1.7145\\ -0.4229 & 0.9862 \end{bmatrix}$.\\
  \textbf{line2.} & Factorize $M L+D+U = \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 0\\ -0.4229 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 1.4216  & 0\\ 0 & 0.9862 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0  & 1.7145\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.\\
  \textbf{line3.} & Compute $R_{\theta}' = (L^T+D+U)R= \begin{bmatrix}  2.4257   & 1.1468\\ 0 & 0.9510 \end{bmatrix}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{IRMf-TEP Comparison}
\label{tab:dif_irm_tep}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `a4wide` is deprecated (and buggy); also `newlfont` should not be used in new documents. I removed the packages unnecessary for the example.

Also `^{'}` is wrong and it should be just `'`.

I also suggest a different approach to tables, with `booktabs`. Vertical rules are suppressed, and `\addlinespace` can be used to give more room and better separate the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\addlinespace
  \textbf{Input} & Given $ A|_{\theta = 0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -1.0000 & 0.4794\\ 1.0000 & 0.2500\\ 0.2298 & 0.0417\\ 0.5000 & -0.5000\\ 0.7702 & 0.3750\\ 0.1250 & 0.5000 \end{bmatrix}$,
  $ A_{\theta}^{'}|_{\theta = 0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -2.000 & 0.8776\\ 2.0000 & 1.0000\\ 0.8415 & 0.2500\\ 1.0000 & 2.0000\\ -0.8415 & 1.7500\\ 0.7500 & 1.0000 \end{bmatrix}$\\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\addlinespace
  \textbf{line1.} & Compute $ M = Q^TA_{\theta}^{'}R^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.4216  & 1.7145\\ -0.4229 & 0.9862 \end{bmatrix}$.\\
\addlinespace
  \textbf{line2.} & Factorize $M L+D+U = \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 0\\ -0.4229 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 1.4216  & 0\\ 0 & 0.9862 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0  & 1.7145\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.\\
\addlinespace
  \textbf{line3.} & Compute $R_{\theta}^{'} = (L^T+D+U)R= \begin{bmatrix}  2.4257   & 1.1468\\ 0 & 0.9510 \end{bmatrix}$ \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{IRMf-TEP Comparison}
\label{tab:dif_irm_tep}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tank you very much @egreg for the response.